# Jquery onChange run a this function

Tags: jquery, onchange, closest

I have created a function called billingOptions() it is associated with a dropdown (select) element. When a user selects an option in the dropdown the function is run.

The  dropdown will dynamically be added through the page...each time adding the billingOptions() function onChange. I am trying to use Jquery to find the closest instance of the class=rate from the dropdown that was changed. Keep in mind that the dropdowns are added dynamically so there could possible be many instances of .rate...

I have tried using "this" and "closest" to find the nearest class (i'm not even sure you can use a class with the closest function). Here is some code:

***I was asked to provide the exact structure of the HTML (the rows of the table are dynamically generated. The table is static).

```
<table id="billTasks"> 
<tr> <input class="taskNameInput" type="text" size="52" placeholder="Task Name" name="task:1" disabled="disabled"> <select class="billOptions" onchange="billingOptions(this)">
<option class="fixedRate">Bill Fixed Rate</option>
<option class="hourly">Bill Hourly</option>
</select> 
<input type="text" name="fixedRate" placeholder="Rate" class="fieldWidth100 rate"/> 
</tr> 
</table>

function billingOptions(){
 $(this).closest('.rate').hide();
}
```

***EDIT: this code does not work. The goal is to hide the input.rate element.

Comment: this looks fine, what issue are you facing?

Comment: does this work correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/vzfyz/

Comment: nothing happens. I have edited the code to show the input with the .rate class.

Comment: No this does not work. I am not sure why. I was thinking 2 main reasons. 
1. this is not being passed to the function
2. closest does not work with classes.

Comment: `closest` traverses the DOM tree upwards, starting with the selected element. If the element you are looking for is not an ancestor of the selected element, `closest` won't find it.

Comment: yes it is an ancestor. What would I use to find an ancestor?

Comment: @mitch - I don't think it is, because an `input` can't contain a `select`. In the example you've posted, it's a sibling. If that's always the case, see the link in my answer to a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** First off, you are half-right about your concern that `this` is not being passed to the function.  It *is* being passed, but it is not being used.  Give your function a named parameter, and reference that instead of `this`:

```
function billingOptions(el)
{
    $(el).something()...
}
```

Is `.rate` always the next element?  If so:

```
$(el).next(".rate").hide();
```

Is `.rate` always a sibling?  Will there only ever be one `.rate` sibling?  If so:

```
$(el).siblings(".rate").hide();
```

Will `.rate` share a common parent with your select, and be the only instance of `.rate` in that common parent?  If so:

```
$(el).closest(".commonParentClassName").find(".rate").hide();
```

If none of these works for you, please provide more detail on the structure of you HTML.

**Edit:**  Thanks for posting the structure of your HTML.  You are missing `<td>` in your HTML.  Assuming your real code includes the `<td>`, and assuming there is only one `.rate` per row, try this:

```
function billingOptions(el)
{
    $(el).closest("tr").find(".rate").hide();
}
```

Comment: none of these worked. Here is the generated HTML: (the rows of the table are dynamically generated. The table is static).
<table id="billTasks">
<tr>
<input class="taskNameInput" type="text" size="52" placeholder="Task Name" name="task:1" disabled="disabled">
<select class="billOptions" onchange="billingOptions(this)">
<input id="fixedRate1" class="fieldWidth100 rate" type="text" placeholder="Rate" name="fixedRate">
</tr>
</table>

Comment: @mitch - I updated my answer with something that will probably address your issue.  See the added paragraph at the top of my answer.

Comment: @mitch - I posted a solution that uses your HTML and correctly references the parameter passed to the function.  See my edit at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really asked a question, other than does closest work with a class, I set up this fiddle to show you that it does:

http://jsfiddle.net/JAjFF/

If you can tell us what is the question, have you tried the code above, does it work? What is the problem if not? Then I will amend my answer.

Comment: No, sorry...it does not work. I have added more detail to my original question. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think this is the issue, but what do I use for an ancestor?

--closest traverses the DOM tree upwards, starting with the selected element. If the element you are looking for is not an ancestor of the selected element, closest won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what your code is trying to do, but there are a couple of problems with it.

Firstly, you are passing a DOM element into your function, but your function has no parameters declared, and you're not accessing the argument you pass in. Also, `this` in this context refers to the Window object, not the element you want it to. Changing it to this (passing in a named argument and using that in place of `this`) would solve that:

```
function billingOptions(elem){
   $(elem).closest('.rate').hide();
}
```

You could alternatively use the `arguments` collection instead of using a named argument, but I would suggest the above method over that.

The next problem is that the `closest` method climbs the DOM tree until it finds the first element that matches the selector you pass it. In your case, as `this` refers to the Window object, `closest` isn't going to find an ancestor matching your selector.

It's also unlikely that the function shown above will solve that problem, as by the look of your code, `.rate` isn't an ancestor of the selected element. I would really need more information on how your HTML is structured to help you select the correct `.rate` element (e.g. is there always going to be a single `.rate` element, inside the same container as the `select`? If that is the case, here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sxqFa/)).

Comment: `this` is not determined by the presence or absence of parameters.  If the function is used this way, it would work:  `$(".billOptions").change(billingOptions)`.  jQuery does not mandate that event handlers be anonymous functions.

Comment: I know it's not... that's why in my example, I've changed `this` to some other variable name. In the function posted in the question, `this` refers to the Window object.

Comment: After re-reading the question, I see that he is not binding his event handler in the way I supposed.  Your comment about `this` is still inaccurate, but not as wrong as I first thought.  You said, "but your function has no parameters declared, so `this` refers to the Window".

Comment: Yes, true. I've not made it very clear. I was trying to get the point across that, a) the function body does not use the argument being passed in, and b) inside that function, `this` refers to the Window object. I will edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Does closest() work with a div? **YES, but it's for ancestor elements**

If your .rate element is on the same level as your SELECT element, you should use .siblings()

If your .rate element is inside your SELECT element, you should use .children()

If your .rate element is right outside of your SELECT element, you should use .parent()

If your .rate element is more then a few levels above your SELECT element, you should then use. closest() to find the closest one.

Also, your function is fine, you just need to update your selector.